# How do I pass the username/password to authenticate a POST request to a Django rest-framework API from python code?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

this is the request I want to emulate in python code, made here with httpie

```
$ http --auth mucho:pass POST http://3333333.ngrok.io/sms/ msg="love conquers all" to="255123456"
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 67
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 30 Dec 2019 20:31:33 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.5
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

{
    "id": 70,
    "msg": "love conquers all",
    "owner": "mucho",
    "to": "255123456"
}
```

I have tried this

```
from requests import Request,Session
url="http://3333333.ngrok.io/sms/"
data = {
    "to": "255123456",
    "msg": "love conquers all",
    }
s=Session()
req=Request('POST',url,data=data)
preped=req.prepare()
preped.prepare_auth(("mucho","pass"),url)
resp=s.send(preped)
```

It works, but I am looking for a neater/simpler way possibly using headers. Thanks for any help my way

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a way to test your api endpoints, you can use [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

It is easy to set the headers.